# Python (TensorFlow) - Concatenating tensor objects with different dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, concatenation, tensor

I have a question regarding concatenating two Tensor object in Tensorflow. As you can see in the code below, I would like to concatenate a2 and b1. a2 has shape (None, 1, 512) and b1 has shape (None, 34, 512). I would like to concatenate them along the second argument, thus axis=1.

```
a_input = Input(shape=(20480,))
b_input = Input(shape=(34,))

a1 = Dense(embedding_dim)(image_input) #N: Activation specification needed here?  # shape = (None, 512)
a2 = K.expand_dims(image_emb, axis=1) # shape = (None, 1, 512)
b1 = Embedding(num_words, embedding_dim, mask_zero=True)(caption_input) # shape = (None, 34, 512)

c = concatenate((a2, b1), axis=1)
```

However, if I execute the code above, I obtain the following error

```
ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 512 and 1. Shapes are [512] and [1]. for '{{node concatenate_28/concat_1}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_BOOL, Tidx=DT_INT32](concatenate_28/ones_like, concatenate_28/ExpandDims, concatenate_28/concat_1/axis)' with input shapes: [?,1,512], [?,34,1], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <1>.
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can this be solved?

Looking forward to some suggestions!

Comment: First, let's check that those dimensions are indeed as you think. Before initializing `c`, place `print(a2, b1)` - this will print tensor objects with their dimensions. Your current code is not reproducible, as you refer to the variables not presented here: `embedding_dim`, `image_emb`, `num_words`...

Comment: I did that, and just put it in comments in the code above. Anyway, I get the following output when printing:

`Tensor("ExpandDims_33:0", shape=(None, 1, 512), dtype=float32) Tensor("embedding_37/Identity:0", shape=(None, 34, 512), dtype=float32)`

Comment: Then try `c = Concatenate(axis=1)([a2, b1])`  (capital letter)

Comment: @Slowpoke I made the changes you suggested and got the same error when running.

Comment: The code I provided works for this snippet: `a2 = Input(shape=(1, 512))
b1 = Input(shape=(34,512))

c = Concatenate(axis=1)([a2, b1])`  Then, it means, as error message suggests, you have problems in your 0 dimension (hidden behind None). As message states, your tensors have 512 and 1 as batch sizes

Comment: @Slowpoke How do I deal with that? How come it already knows these batch sizes if I have not yet inputnthem? I agree that the issues seems to be on the 0 dimension, but the error message also confuses me a little since it states that the input tensors are [?,1,512], [?,34,1]. Here the last dimension differ, to my surprise.

Comment: Try to make experiment with batch size fixed ( `shape=, batch_size=` arguments for both `keras` and `tf.keras`)  https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/input/  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input

Comment: For the last dimension you can do something like hotfix using lambda: `x = Lambda(lambda t: tf.transpose(t, (0,2,1)))(x)`

Comment: The issue turned out to be `mask_zero=True`. If I put `mask_zero=False`, it is working :)

Comment: @Student NL, Can you please confirm if the error is resolved with the `mask_zero=False,` so that we can mention it as an answer for the benefit of the community. Else, please share reproducible code so that we can help you.Thanks !

Comment: @TensorflowWarriors As I said in my previous comment, setting `mask_zero=False` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the comment section for the benefit of the community.

```
ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 512 and 1. Shapes are [512] and [1]. for '{{node concatenate_28/concat_1}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_BOOL, Tidx=DT_INT32](concatenate_28/ones_like, concatenate_28/ExpandDims, concatenate_28/concat_1/axis)' with input shapes: [?,1,512], [?,34,1], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <1>.
```

This error was resolved when modifying code from

```
b1 = Embedding(num_words, embedding_dim, mask_zero=True)(caption_input)
```

to

```
b1 = Embedding(num_words, embedding_dim, mask_zero=False)(caption_input)
```

Complete updated code in below

```
a_input = Input(shape=(20480,))
b_input = Input(shape=(34,))

a1 = Dense(embedding_dim)(image_input) #N: Activation specification needed here?  # shape = (None, 512)
a2 = K.expand_dims(image_emb, axis=1) # shape = (None, 1, 512)
b1 = Embedding(num_words, embedding_dim, mask_zero=False)(caption_input) # shape = (None, 34, 512)

c = concatenate((a2, b1), axis=1)
```